# I am trying to implement Postcode Anywhere into my site

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement Postcode Anywhere into my site.So if they enter the post code in the incident postal code field the system will show addresses related to that post code and the user will select the relevant address, the address details will then populate the rest of the incident address field.I am using the following code in my page:

```
function CapturePlus_Interactive_Find_v2_10Begin(Key, SearchTerm, LastId, SearchFor, Country, LanguagePreference, MaxSuggestions, MaxResults) {
    var script = document.createElement("script"),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        url = "http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/CapturePlus/Interactive/Find/v2.10/json3.ws?";

    // Build the query string
    url += "&Key=" + encodeURIComponent(Key);
    url += "&SearchTerm=" + encodeURIComponent(SearchTerm);
    url += "&LastId=" + encodeURIComponent(LastId);
    url += "&SearchFor=" + encodeURIComponent(SearchFor);
    url += "&Country=" + encodeURIComponent(Country);
    url += "&LanguagePreference=" + encodeURIComponent(LanguagePreference);
    url += "&MaxSuggestions=" + encodeURIComponent(MaxSuggestions);
    url += "&MaxResults=" + encodeURIComponent(MaxResults);
    url += "&callback=CapturePlus_Interactive_Find_v2_10End";

    script.src = url;

    // Make the request
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") {
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (head && script.parentNode)
                head.removeChild(script);
        }
    }

    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
}

function CapturePlus_Interactive_Find_v2_10End(response) {
    // Test for an error
    if (response.Items.length == 1 && typeof(response.Items[0].Error) != "undefined") {
        // Show the error message
        alert(response.Items[0].Description);
    }
    else {
        // Check if there were any items found
        if (response.Items.length == 0)
            alert("Sorry, there were no results");
        else {
            // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
            //FYI: The output is an array of key value pairs (e.g. response.Items[0].Id), the keys being:
            //Id
            //Text
            //Highlight
            //Cursor
            //Description
            //Next
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is to be written in the else part of the code (where I need to put the actual code to map the values). Can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: So you copied the code from http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/ and want some help here.. show what you done.

Answer (score 0):

if you look on there site, there is a working example. Look at code behind of page

http://www.pcapredict.com/support/webservice/captureplus/interactive/find/2.1/

Good luck

```
function TestCallBack(response){
var _strHtml='';
var _intColumn=0;
var _intRow=0;
var _strColumns= new Array('Id','Text','Highlight','Cursor','Description','Next');
var _strColumn='';
//Hide the waiting panel
document.getElementById('btnTest').innerHTML = 'Start the test';
document.getElementById('btnTest').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('pnlOutput').style.display='block';
//Test for an error
if (response.length==1 && typeof(response[0].Error) != 'undefined'){
//Show the error message
_strHtml = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="doc-table" style="width: 100%;">';
_strHtml += '<thead><tr><th><span class="cboxtl"></span>Error</th><th>Description</th><th>Cause</th><th><span class="cboxtr"></span>Resolution</th></tr></thead>';
_strHtml += '<tr><td>' + response[0].Error + '</td><td>' + response[0].Description + '</td><td>' + response[0].Cause + '</td><td>' + response[0].Resolution + '</td></tr>';
_strHtml += '</table>';
//Update the DIV
document.getElementById('pnlHeading').innerHTML = '<h2>Error</h2>';
document.getElementById('pnlError').innerHTML =  _strHtml;
document.getElementById('pnlError').style.display='block';
}
else{
//Check if there were any items found
if (response.length==0){
_strHtml = '<h2>Sorry, no matching items found</h2>';
}
else{
//Add the headings to the table
_strHtml += '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="doc-table" style="width: 100%; table-layout:auto;">';
_strHtml += '<thead><tr>';
for (_intColumn=0; _intColumn<_strColumns.length; _intColumn++)
{
_strHtml += '<th>' + _strColumns[_intColumn] + '</th>';
}
_strHtml += '</tr></thead>';
//Add the rows
for (_intRow=0; _intRow<response.length; _intRow++){
_strHtml += '<tr>'
if (response[_intRow].Id=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Id + '</td>' };
if (response[_intRow].Text=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Text + '</td>' };
if (response[_intRow].Highlight=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Highlight + '</td>' };
if (response[_intRow].Cursor=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Cursor + '</td>' };
if (response[_intRow].Description=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Description + '</td>' };
if (response[_intRow].Next=='') { _strHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>' } else  { _strHtml += '<td>' + response[_intRow].Next + '</td>' };
_strHtml += '</tr>'
}
_strHtml += '</table>'
}
//Update the DIV
document.getElementById('pnlHeading').innerHTML = '<h3>Results</h3>';
document.getElementById('pnlResults').innerHTML = _strHtml;
document.getElementById('pnlResults').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('pnlError').style.display='none';
}
}
```

Comment: The code u have given will just create a table of the values.What I want is,When user starts typing the postalcode in the postalcode field, a dropdown of the addresses of the related post code should be shown.

Comment: I was asked to use the code that I have pasted above.But i dont know what code should be added in the else part so that i get a dropdown when i start typing the postal code